# Promise equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, promise, async-await, task, future

In Scala there is a Promise class that could be used to complete a Future manually. I am looking for an alternative in C#.

I am writing a test and I want it to look it similar to this:

```
// var MyResult has a field `Header`
var promise = new Promise<MyResult>;

handlerMyEventsWithHandler( msg =>
    promise.Complete(msg);
);

// Wait for 2 seconds
var myResult = promise.Future.Await(2000);

Assert.Equals("my header", myResult.Header);
```

I understand that this is probably not the right pattern for C#, but I couldn't figure out a reasonable way to achieve the same thing even with somewhat different pattern.

EDIT: please note, that `async`/`await` doesn't help here, as I don't have a Task to await! I just have an access to a handler that will be run on another thread.

Comment: I think you are looking for `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

In C#:

- `Task<T>` is a future (or `Task` for a unit-returning future).
- `TaskCompletionSource<T>` is a promise.

So your code would translate as such:

```
// var promise = new Promise<MyResult>;
var promise = new TaskCompletionSource<MyResult>();

// handlerMyEventsWithHandler(msg => promise.Complete(msg););
handlerMyEventsWithHandler(msg => promise.TrySetResult(msg));

// var myResult = promise.Future.Await(2000);
var completed = await Task.WhenAny(promise.Task, Task.Delay(2000));
if (completed == promise.Task)
  ; // Do something on timeout
var myResult = await completed;

Assert.Equals("my header", myResult.Header);
```

The "timed asynchronous wait" is a bit awkward, but it's also relatively uncommon in real-world code. For unit tests, I would just do a regular asynchronous wait:

```
var promise = new TaskCompletionSource<MyResult>();

handlerMyEventsWithHandler(msg => promise.TrySetResult(msg));

var myResult = await promise.Task;

Assert.Equals("my header", myResult.Header);
```

Comment: There is a nicer way to implement timeouts using cancellation tokens. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/23476576/1288449

Comment: @StevenLiekens: I agree that timeouts are generally better represented as cancellation tokens; however, that's best for situations where timeouts are used to cancel an operation. In this scenario, we're talking about cancelling the *wait*, not the *operation*, and cancellation tokens are more awkward in this scenario.

Answer (score 22):

The rough C# equivalent without third-party libraries would be:

```
// var MyResult has a field `Header`
var promise = new TaskCompletionSource<MyResult>();

handlerMyEventsWithHandler(msg =>
  promise.SetResult(msg)
);

// Wait for 2 seconds
if (promise.Task.Wait(2000))
{
  var myResult = promise.Task.Result;
  Debug.Assert("my header" == myResult.Header);
}
```

Note that it is usually best to use the `await`/`async` to as high a level as possible. Accessing the `Result` of a `Task` or using `Wait` can in some cases [introduce deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15021304/2101267).

Comment: @Stephen's answer is pure C#. What is different here.

Comment: @SahibKhan, 1. I posted before him and 2. This is pure C# too, though maybe not best practice any longer.

Answer (score 7):

You can use C# Promises library

Open sourced on Github: https://github.com/Real-Serious-Games/C-Sharp-Promise

Available on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RSG.Promise/

Comment: You can read more about it on my blog: http://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/promises-for-game-development/

Answer (score 5):

This is the old school way of doing Promises.
Back then i believe it was called synchronization :)

```
MyResult result = null;
var are = new AutoResetEvent(false);

handlerMyEventsWithHandler( 
    msg => {result = msg; are.Set();}
);

// Wait for 2 seconds
if(!are.WaitOne(2000)) {/* handle timeout... */}

Assert.Equals("my header", myResult.Header);
```

Just for Completeness - to large for a comment.
**I agree with [Stephen Cleary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38998516/568857).**

But if you are building a facade around some legacy code this can be used to wrap old API's in a Task like:

```cs
public Task<MyResult> GetResultAsync() {
    MyResult result = null;
    var are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    handlerMyEventsWithHandler(msg => {
        result = msg;
        are.Set();
    });
    are.WaitOne();
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try looking into the async model. Tasks are the nearest equivalent in c#.

[Here's a link to an MS Article explaining their use.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can download future(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Future/) package from Nuget and can be used as below

```
        Promise<int> promise = new Promise<int>();
        new Task(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            promise.Set(20);

        }).Start();
        int result=promise.Get();
```

As per the example you can create a promise object and do a get to get result, get will wait until result is on the object. You do a set from another thread as show in the above example.

This package provides the below two classes

1. Promise : Which waits indefinitely for the result
2. TimedPromise : Which waits for the result only till the specified time. If result is not available with in the time, it throws timeout exception