# How can I await until I receive a callback/notification without busy-waiting?

Tags: c#, async-await, event-driven

I understand how I can `await` on library code to wait for a network request or other long-running action to complete, but how can I `await` on my own long-running action **without busy waiting**?

---

This is the busy-waiting solution. How can I make it event-driven?

```cs
public async Task<DataBlock> ClickSend() {
    // await until someone calls DataReceived()
    while (_Block == null) {
        await Task.Yield();
    }
    return _Block;
}

// Something external calls this function.
// Once called, ClickSend should complete with this data.
public void DataReceived(DataBlock data_block) {
    _Block = data_block;
}
DataBlock _Block = null;
```

*(This question is completely different from [How do I await events in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761852/how-do-i-await-events-in-c) which is asking how to await on event handlers, but very similar to [Promise equivalent in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996593/promise-equivalent-in-c-sharp).)*

Comment: @PeterDuniho: None of the answers on [How do I await events in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761852/how-do-i-await-events-in-c) suggest using a `TaskCompletionSource`. I agree that the the two questions appear to be asking the same question, but the intent is quite different. I don't care about the async behaviour of the `event` keyword and they don't care about TaskCompletionSource.

Comment: You're right that the answer is very similar to "what is a promise in C#", but it's hard to find that question if you don't know what you're looking for (a promise) and the questions is phrased in terms of another language. I posed this question because it is free of that context so it's more broadly useful. (I don't see any "this may be a duplicate" links that you're referring to -- just your comment.)

Comment: You can see the revision history for the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67611867/revisions), which shows the post I mistakenly used for the duplicate target, and then the correct one I added right after. It's unfortunate that I didn't notice the error of the first link, since that would have been the right time for me to fix it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generally in concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) a "future" is placeholder for a return value and it has an associated "promise" that is fulfilled to pass the final return value.

In C#, they have different names: the future is a Task and [the promise is a TaskCompletionSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996593/promise-equivalent-in-c-sharp).

You can create a promise, await on it, and then fulfill it when you get your callback:

```cs
TaskCompletionSource<DataBlock> _Promise = new TaskCompletionSource<DataBlock>();

public async Task<DataBlock> ClickSend() {
    DataBlock block = await _Promise.Task;
    return block;
}

public void DataReceived(DataBlock data_block) {
    _Promise.TrySetResult(data_block);
}
```

[Here's an executable example](https://tio.run/##5VTLbtswELzrKxZGDwrQMulZdQ9xemvRwgoQFEVh0NTWIkyRAR92DcPf7pKiHlQc9JFreTBk7ezuzOyKzLxhSuP57AyXGygPxmJTZOk/cl9rpJV/Qe6p2Zoiyx7dWnAGTFBj4I5aeisU28IxA3@6IJcWViEGc7gpslOWRfitM4cHyu0UTc1BMgj13w313sPCh7Ylyiq/6uDhXF8D3YcKTlouwKgGlURgVIjIZokM@Q591pCzr7lAyFeR6HwO0gmRFg0nVg0kyFeOwucXQ/w0PGm0TkuIpSLAi@uIlZ6MrYN5@NOillR0vPxLAz@cZJYrSXr4Z8kicaxej2rB1MqJCphqHgVahD23daxQeXkkNW6neDUVPc4jgFfr8Jgq7T1Iwr2K8DumD8DgVZE9Py5YOjmZzo5qaIuuaiorb/o8HeNo6ISzxP3Y@DjszdsbOCUpQ2kfirNKG424hZJGCSQPmlv8yCXmr2Z9Kzi2OaRtcZpd9dKH/fywQ2nvtMfK7MUrOpo45bv6olXDDbZfUvF0pdYXG/XyIQ@N9KFEu0TjhM0T7KRNYLOIy@a3s1ROM0xF9tXCLvhJ/QEepvyfLIv3ZaNp0ykyltqp3k@Uy9xY7S@Eb9@B6o1J1V@2npWWahuuj2QNCSGzJ8L6SSSo1K6oF0lr9@@kzroxYtvhr4j19/czrNYdqx5ySWn9r5R6v8/nXw).