# C# Setting WriteTimeout / ReadTimeout on Network Stream Makes No Difference?

Tags: c#, timeout, networkstream

I have following method code in my Xamarin.Forms application

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip, port))
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    byte[] messageBytes = PrepareMessageBytes();

    //
    // Setting these seam to have no effect
    //
    stream.WriteTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds;
    stream.ReadTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds;

    //
    // I have set read and write timeouts above but when 
    // hitting this line, app hangs indefinitely?  
    // I would expect that after 10 seconds, a IOException
    // will be thrown
    await stream.WriteAsync(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
    stream.Flush();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while (stream.DataAvailable)
    {
        bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        builder.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
    }

    string msg = receivedMessage.ToString();
}
```

Above, I have set both Write and Read timeouts to 10 seconds.  I know my code hangs on call to:

await stream.WriteAsync(...)

, but I would expect that after 10 seconds, an IOException will be thrown.  Based on MS documentation, that is not the case for async writes/reads.

How do I set timeout for calls to WriteAsync / ReadAsync methods?

**UPDATE - 2ND ATTEMPT BASED ON STEPHEN'S COMMENT**

Based on Stephen's comment, I updated the code and wrapped it into try..catch to handle OperationCancelledException. **But this is causing even more issues now than before and the App will still hang most of the time**:

```
try
{
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip, port))
    using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
    using (var writeCts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
    {
        byte[] messageBytes = PrepareMessageBytes();

        await stream.WriteAsync(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length, writeCts.Token);
        await stream.FlushAsync();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while (stream.DataAvailable)
        {
            using (var readCts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
                bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, readCts.Token);
            builder.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
        }

        string msg = receivedMessage.ToString();
    }
catch (OperationCancelledException ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WriteAsync with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47784152/writeasync-with-timeout)

Answer (score 2):

> How do I set timeout for calls to WriteAsync / ReadAsync methods?

You use the overload that takes a `CancellationToken` parameter:

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip, port))
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
using (var writeCts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
{
    byte[] messageBytes = PrepareMessageBytes();

    await stream.WriteAsync(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length, writeCts.Token);
    await stream.FlushAsync();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while (stream.DataAvailable)
    {
        using (var readCts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
            bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, readCts.Token);
        builder.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
    }

    string msg = receivedMessage.ToString();
}
```

> I would expect that after 10 seconds, an IOException will be thrown.

When using cancellation tokens, expect an `OperationCanceledException`. Technically, cancellation tokens can be used for a wide variety of cancellation scenarios - the code decides it doesn't need to complete the operation anymore, the user manually canceled the operation, or there was a timeout. `OperationCanceledException` is the generic exception type meaning "canceled".

Comment: Thanks Stephen, so wrapping the code above into try...catch with OperationCancellationException should catch cancellation exception I guess however, I dont see that to happen most of the time.  I see the execution hanging instead when I run app.  If I am debugging, I do see cancellation exception being cought by my catch block but not after 10 seconds, it takes longer than that.  I also have a feeling that app hangs in various parts now, but mostly on call to WriteAsync.  Sometimes I pass that point but on 2nd call to same method it hangs forever.  it is almost as something is not getng cleard